# No connection of internet visual studio Apache cordova app

Tags: windows, visual-studio, apache-cordova

I built apache cordova app in visual studio and also run it in windows emulator. It was opened in emulator but while I was using the app the app it showing internet connection error. I checked all the setting in system, emulator and also app permission all were fine. But still it was showing internet connection error I am unable find exact error any other. Internet working for emulator other than the app. I tried many ways, I did hyper-v settings also. what are the settings needed please suggest me.